# r reading multiple txt files into multiple data frames

Tags: regex, r

I need to read multiple txt files into separate vectors and I'm stuck with the script.

This single calls works fine:

```
setwd("~/Documents/DSC")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
j1<-read.table("qBlog 1 .txt", encoding="latin1")
j2<-read.table("qBlog 2 .txt", encoding="latin1")
```

but when I try a for call:

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
  oname = paste("./blogSample/qBlog ", i, sep="")
  assign(oname, read.table(paste("\"",oname, " .txt\"",",encoding=\"latin1\"", sep="")))
```

I get the following error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '"./blogSample/qBlog 1 .txt",encoding="latin1"': Invalid argument
```

I believe is a regex problem but I can't see what I´m doing wrong!!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't put `encoding="latin1"` between quotes. Also, don't use `assign`, but create a `list` of `data.frame`s through `lapply`: `oname <- paste("./blogSample/qBlog ", 1:10, " .txt", sep="");lapply(oname, read.table, encoding="latin1")`

Comment: @nicola: Thanks for your help! However when I tried:     `for(i in 1:10)
{
lapply: oname <- paste("./blogSample/qBlog ", 1:10, sep="");
lapply(oname, read.table, encoding="latin1")
}`           I get the following error:            `Error in lapply:oname <- paste("./blogSample/qBlog ", 1:10, sep = "") : 
  could not find function ":<-"`

Comment: No need of any loop! Just copy/paste what I wrote _after_ `lapply:`. The line starts with `oname`.

Comment: @nicola: I just understand your code and executed exactly as you mencioned when your response arrived. It works fine, thank you very much!